# .NET analogue of Python's glob?

Tags: c#, .net

Python's [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module lets you search for files matching a particular pattern. For example `glob.glob("*.jpg")` would list all jpegs in the working directory.

A more complex example using the double asterisk `**` syntax to search all subfolders of 'pics' for cat photos:

```
glob.glob("pics/**/*cat*.jpg", recursive=True)
```

Is there any similar function in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

[Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is possibly a closest that comes to mind. However you can use only standard Windows wildcards (pretty sure that `**` functionality is not supported). However you can filter results after you get them if that is tolerable solution.